# Docker-compose up error: Cannot create container for service notebook: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind mount source path does not exist

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I copied a docker image from computer to another, then I did a `docker-compose up` but I got the error below. I have done this operation before on other computers and it worked fine (just copying the image from one computer to another and then launch `docker-compose up`), but this time it doesn't. Any ideas on why I got this issue?

Note also that the file `.env` exists and is correctly place in the same folder as the `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
mart23@abc549:~/Documents/docker/repos/operations/notebooks$ docker-compose up
WARNING: Service "notebook" uses secret "dock_secret" which is external.
External secrets are not available to containers created by docker-compose.
Creating my_notebook ... error
ERROR: for my_notebook  Cannot create container for service notebook:
invalid mount config for type "bind": bind mount source path does not exist:
/home/mart23/Documents/docker/repos/operations/notebooks/.env
ERROR: for notebook  Cannot create container for service notebook: 
invalid mount config for type "bind": bind mount source path does not exist:
/home/mart23/Documents/docker/repos/operations/notebooks/.env
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Comment: It is saying that the file you are trying to bind mount does not exist, does `/home/mart23/Documents/docker/repos/operations/notebooks/.env` exist on your system?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in my question, the file ``.env`` already exists in that path

Comment: I think the problem is related to the fact that the files are not shared between the docker image and the host. The folder ``/mnt/`` is empty in my docker image. How can I share the files?